# Configure max_allowed_packet on mySQL SERVER on AWS-EC2

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance created with a MySQL server instance installed.
Since i am sending large blob data to be stored in the server, and the `max_allowed_packet` configuration is set to value `1048576`, my service requests are failing.

I am trying to increase the size of the parameter to 16MB by using the below command via putty.

```
SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=16777216;
```

But there is no effect in the parameter. I tried restarting the sql server instance, still the effect isnt seen. 
When i run the below command again after setting the parameter, the same old value is shown 1048576.

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';
```

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the MySQL server's configuration file `/etc/my.cnf` under `[mysqld]` section with the new value for `max_allowed_packet`

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet=16M
```

and restart the server.

Values set via `SET` statement are not persisted across server restarts and are applied only on the new client sessions created after the change.

Excerpt from the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-variable.html),

> If you change a global system variable, the value is remembered and
>   used to initialize the session value for new sessions until you change
>   the variable to a different value or the server exits. The change is
>   visible to any client that accesses the global value. However, the
>   change affects the corresponding session value only for clients that
>   connect after the change. The global variable change does not affect
>   the session value for any current client sessions (not even the
>   session within which the global value change occurs).